# Pattern not replaced using appendReplacement

Tags: java, regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?:[a-zA-Z]\\.)+[s]$)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("u.s.a. u.s s.w.a.t u.t.");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, "$0\\#");
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
```

Here `u.s` should be replaced by `u.s#` but it is not replacing it. In my application I need to append any acronym ending with `s` or `s.` with a `#`.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"((?:[a-zA-Z]\\.)+s\\.?(?=\\s|$))"
```

You need to use this and use `find` instead of `matches` as `matches` asserts that the whole string matches the regex. `$` is end of string, so use lookahead instead.

https://regex101.com/r/cT0hV4/1

Comment: Oh ok. I check that. Is there any way I can modify the expression to that it also matched strings ending with `s.` ?

Comment: "`find` instead of `matcher`" doesn't make any sense, you probably mean `matches`, but the OP is already using `find`.

Comment: @vks: Well, the question doesn't retain any edit history of that, so you might want to remove that part from your answer.